# How to convert similar Json objects to Json Arrays with Gson and Retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

Let's say I'm getting below response from API

```
{"success":true,
"base":"EUR",
"date":"2021-04-16",
"rates":
{"AED":4.393943,"AFN":92.83145,"ALL":123.125765,"AMD":621.059723}}
```

and I want the last rates object to be a List of Rate class i.e. Rate(code="AED", value="4.393943"). I am using Retrofit and Gson. I know I need a Deserializer or a Type Adapter. I just don't know how to write one.

Rate Class:

```
data class Rate(
    val code:String,
    val value:Float
)
```

Currency Class:

```
data class Currency(
    @SerializedName("success")
    val success: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("base")
    val base: String?,
    @SerializedName("date")
    val date: Date?,
    @SerializedName("rates")
    val rates: List<Rate>?
)
```

This is the request:

```
val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Rate::class.java, TypeAdapterOrDeserializer())
    .create()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.exchangerate.host")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
val jsonPlaceholderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderApi::class.java)
val call = jsonPlaceholderApi.currency
```

When I request data from api it gives this error, I know why ;) as I have given List of Rates in Currency class but it is a json rate object.
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for `rates` returned by the API is a JSON object, but in your data class you defined it as a `List` so `Gson` expects it to be a JSON array. You would need custom parsing for your `Currency` class in this case.

Use this deserializer:

```
class CurrencyDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Currency> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): Currency {
        if (json == null || context == null) {
            // handle error here
            throw Exception("Error")
        }
        val obj = json.asJsonObject

        // let Gson handle the other 3 properties
        val success = context.deserialize<Boolean?>(obj.get("success"), Boolean::class.java)
        val base = context.deserialize<String?>(obj.get("base"), String::class.java)
        val date = context.deserialize<Date?>(obj.get("date"), Date::class.java)

        // create List<Rate> from the rates JsonObject
        val ratesSet = obj.get("rates").asJsonObject.entrySet()
        val ratesList = ratesSet.map {
            val code = it.key
            val value = it.value.asFloat
            Rate(code, value)
        }

        return Currency(success, base, date, ratesList)
    }
}
```

Add it to `Gson` like this:

```
val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Currency::class.java, CurrencyDeserializer())
    .create()
```

Comment: @PrathameshMore in that case please mark it as the answer so it can help others as well.